# Blazor App: Container.ReadItemAsync fails to connect to Azure Database when AddAuthentication used

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor

I'm using C# in Visual Studios to create a Blazor App to connect to an Azure Database. Bit new to Blazor/Azure but I managed to get it working and retrieve the data.

I was initially using IServiceCollection.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie()

This all works fine, I'm looking to use Azure's Active Directory to verify users, which seems to work on its own, but now when the code does:
await Container.ReadItemAsync
it doesn't return the ItemResponse (or anything at all).

I've tried Googling the issue, but I haven't found anything relevant. I assume that there is an issue connecting to the azure DB relating to permissions, but I can't work out how to change it. Being new to cloud development, I'm not versed in the lingo. :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Instead of string use JObject to return value.

instead of:

```
ItemResponse<string> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<string>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);
```

use this code:

```
ItemResponse<JObject> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);
```

return result.Resource.ToString();